# VUFORIA Ground plane detection & Rigid Body

Tags: unity-game-engine, vuforia, rigid-bodies

Friends, I need a support.. I tried using VUFORIA GROUND PLANE DETECTION with Unity 2018.1

I found that when I add rigid body to the objects that I need to place on the plane, the objects just fall through the ground plane.. (I have added the collider to the ground plane as well)..

I also was able to recognise that the colliders get disabled until the object is placed on the plane itself.. So tried using ISKINEMATIC until the object is recognised on the plane and tried to disable the ISKINEMATIC once the object is recognised on the plane.. But this did not work even..

Can anyone support me with the solution to this problem??

Answer (score 0):

I met same problem in Unity v2018.2.0f2.
         My solution is **freeze constraints position Y** to avoid physic object fall down.
         After user click on plane detection to put the object, I unfreeze it.
         You can check my [github](https://github.com/lcd11001/unity-vuforia-ground-plane)
Regards,
LCD

Comment: Hi there.. i found another way to sort this out.. adding rigidbody to the ground plane itself ceases this error..